# Docker re-build time

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

We are trying to create a Docker container for a python application. The Dockerfile installs dependencies using "pip install". The Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y git wget python3-pip
RUN mkdir /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip3 install asn1crypto
RUN pip3 install cffi==1.10.0
RUN pip3 install click==6.7
RUN pip3 install conda==4.3.16
RUN pip3 install Flask==0.12.2
RUN pip3 install Flask-SSLify==0.1.5
RUN pip3 install Flask-SSLify==0.1.5
RUN pip3 install flask-restful==0.3.6
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD [ "X.py", "/app/Y.yml" ]
```

The docker gets created successfully the issue is on the rebuild time.

- If nothing is changed in the dockerfile above
- If a line is changed in the dockerfile which is after pip install the docker daemon still runs all the commands in pip install, downloading all the packages though not installing them.

Is there a way to optimize the rebuild?

Thx

Comment: If a file copied by the `COPY` command has chanced it will create a new layer with a new hash and the cache can't be used anymore. Try to move the `COPY` below the `pip` calls.

Comment: I'd also suggest reading [docker best practices](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/) -- there's a few other issues with the dockerfile as written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is what i would like to do momentarily with the Dockerfile for optimization -

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    wget \
    python3-pip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
WORKDIR /app  
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD [ "X.py", "/app/Y.yml" ]
```

- Reduce the layers by integrating multiple commands into a single one specifically when they are interdependent. This helps reducing the image size.
- Always try to use the COPY at the end since a regular source code change may invalidate the next layer caching.
- Use a single requirements.txt file for installation through pip. Also define separate steps in case you have lots of packages to install, don't let a normal source code change force packages installation on every build.
- Always cleanup the intermediate things which are not required in the final image.

Ref- https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: Won't this copy every-time change the docker checksum?COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

Comment: @Vaibhav - Why do you think it will change every-time?
I believe It won't change every-time, it will change only if you commit a change in "requirements.txt" file. If we don't do this extra step a normal source code change will force packages installation on every build.

Comment: If you see above comments the COPY ./app and COPY ./requirements probably makes the difference. I though have not yet checked.

Comment: So let's say if we don't put extra command for copying the requirement file, in that case you have to copy your source code before doing a "pip install -r" & a change in source code will invalidate the cache & will install the packages on every source code change. If your application needs lots of packages to be installed then probably you won't like them to get installed on every code change. However you have a different COPY step, it will install packages only if there is a change in requirements.txt file. Please try it whenever you get a chance.